# How to overwrite a method of a dynamically created class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

A class I cannot change the code of has a method `from_lowercase` that returns an instance of itself. Now I would like to inherit a class. However, when calling the inherited class over `from_lowercase` an instance of the original class is returned.

```py
class Animal:
    """I CANNOT change the code in this class"""
    def __init__(self, uppercase_name: str):
        self.uppercase_name = uppercase_name

    def say(self) -> str:
        return f"I am {self.uppercase_name}"

    @staticmethod
    def from_lowercase(lowercase_name: str) -> "Animal":
        return Animal(lowercase_name.upper())


class PoliteAnimal(Animal):
    def say(self) -> str:
        return f"Hello dear sir, {super().say()}!"
    # insert magic here
```

calling some examples:

```py
animal = Animal("JOHN")
animal_from_lowercase = Animal.from_lowercase("john")
nice_animal = PoliteAnimal("MARIA")
nice_animal_from_lowercase = PoliteAnimal.from_lowercase("maria")

print(animal.say())
print(animal_from_lowercase.say())
print(nice_animal.say())
print(nice_animal_from_lowercase.say())
```

leads to the following:

```py
I am JOHN
I am JOHN
Hello dear sir, I am MARIA!
I am MARIA
```

However, the desired output is the following:

```py
I am JOHN
I am JOHN
Hello dear sir, I am MARIA!
Hello dear sir, I am MARIA!
```

Obviously `nice_animal_from_lowercase` is an instance of `Animal` and not `PoliteAnimal`. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the same method on your subclass so it will be overridden

```
class PoliteAnimal(Animal):
    def say(self) -> str:
        return f"Hello dear sir, {super().say()}!"
    # insert magic here
    @staticmethod
    def from_lowercase(lowercase_name: str) -> "Animal":
        return PoliteAnimal(lowercase_name.upper())
```

Ouput:

```
I am JOHN
I am JOHN
Hello dear sir, I am MARIA!
Hello dear sir, I am MARIA!
```

Comment: Thank you but I do not want to copy code from Animal since it could be in an external library

Answer (score 2):

I would patch `Animal` to fix `from_lowercase`, which should be a class method, not a static method.

```
def from_lowercase(cls, lc: str):
    return cls(lc.upper())

Animal.from_lowercase = classmethod(from_lowercase)
```

This works even if you do it after `PoliteAnimal` is defined.

When you call `PoliteAnimal.from_lowercase(...)`, the method lookup will result in a call to `Animal.from_lowercase`, but as a class method it will receive `PoliteAnimal` as its first argument, leading to the correct class being instantiated.

Comment: @ToM: FYI this technique is called [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch)  — also see question [What is a monkey patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-a-monkey-patch)

Comment: The Problem is that in reality `from_lowercase` is a much more complex function of an external library. So I cannot simply rewrite it.

Comment: Can you write a wrapper that will create a subclass instance given an instance of `Animal`?

Comment: I don't think so. What exactly are you proposing?

Comment: Something like `PoliteAnimal.from_animal(Animal.from_lowercase("john"))`. `Animal.from_lowercase` seems like its the problem, but without more details about your *actual* class, it's difficult to provide a good solution.